# Environ("username") error on /Windows 7 64 bit computer

Tags: vba

We are running a Microsoft Visual Basic application inside of Microsoft Word 2007. Data is written to Access 2000 or 2002 databases. It functions correctly within a Windows Vista 32 bit operating system without any issues. However when the same visual basic code is run on a Windows 7 64 bit operating system using Microsoft Word 2007, the following VB **error** is displayed:

```
username2 = Environ("username")
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Try `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`

---

Try `VBA.Environ("username")`

I'm not on Windows 7 currently, but I will be later today to test furthermore if still no solution is found.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I haven't been able to find any VBA coding I could substitute intead so far.

Comment: If none of the above work, it is probably an issue with the specific system you're on (not necessarily related to the fact it's W7). Check in the References list (go `Tools --> References..`) if there are any missing ones. If so, they'll start with "MISSING" and should be disabled.

Comment: I checked the references list, and noticed the file for the Microsoft Calender Control 2007 was missing. I copied it from my Windows Vista computer (c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\mscal.ocx) to my Windows 7 computer (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\office12\mscal.ocx). Also, we needed to create a global variable for Environ("username"), and everything seems to work okay. Would we need to ensure that mscal.ocx would need to be present on all Windows 7 computers which would be using the 
MS Visual Basic application. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Also is MSADODC OCX similar to the mscal.ocx? I know by doing some research it is used for a connection to an Access database. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the below function from [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm) extensively and not run into problems. I had several with the method you are describing.

```
Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
"GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Function fOSUserName() As String
' Returns the network login name
Dim lngLen As Long, lngX As Long
Dim strUserName As String
    strUserName = String$(254, 0)
    lngLen = 255
    lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
    If (lngX > 0) Then
        fOSUserName = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1)
    Else
        fOSUserName = vbNullString
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will note the funtion if we need to use it in the future. Much appreciated :)